# making a a ghjoov

Tags: javascript

one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen twenty twenty one twenty two twenty three twenty four twenty five

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems.

**First - mouseOnCircle is Empty**

Your `mouseOnCircle` function is empty. As such, it doesn't return a value, so `if (mouseOnCircle(x, y, radius))` evaluates to `false`, so `context.clearRect` is never called. Also, `context` is not defined in this scope, so I think it should be `ctx.clearRect` instead.

**Second - Tracking Drawn Circles**

You're referencing `x`, `y` and `radius` variables in `removeCircle`, but those variables are not in scope so they're `undefined`. You may want to track the circles that have been drawn, so at the beginning of the script you could have `const circles = [];`. At the end of `drawCircle` below `ctx.fill()` you could do:

```js
function drawCircle() {
    // Draw the circle

    // Add it to the list of circles
    circles.push({ x, y, radius });
}
```

**Third - Hit Detection**

New function called `doesIntersectCircle`:

```js
function doesIntersectCircle(point, circle) {
    return Math.sqrt((point.x-circle.x) ** 2 + (point.y - circle.y) ** 2) < circle.radius;
}
```

`removeCircle` should look like this:

```js
function removeCircle(e) {    // <-- e is the event object
    const pos = {
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY
    };

    // Check each circle for intersection with the click point
    // If intersected, clear it
    const newCircles = [];
    circles.forEach(circle => {
        if (doesIntersectCircle(pos, circle)) {
            // Although, this clears the entire canvas
            // You probably need to just clear the area of the given circle
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        } else {
            // Keep the circle
            newCircles.push(circle);
        }
    });
    circles.splice(0, circles.length);
    circles.push(...newCircles);
}
```

`mouseOnCircle` is not needed, that's handled in `removeCircle`.

**Working Example**

*I moved the incrementing of `numberOfClicks` and `console.log(numberOfClicks);` inside `removeCircle`.*

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var numberOfClicks = 0;

const circles = [];

function doesIntersectCircle(point, circle) {
    return Math.sqrt((point.x-circle.x) ** 2 + (point.y - circle.y) ** 2) < circle.radius;
}

function run() {
  setInterval(drawCircle, 500);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (removeCircle));
}

function drawCircle() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 580);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 580);
  var radius = 20;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  //ctx.fillStyle();
  ctx.fill();
  circles.push({ x, y, radius });
}

function removeCircle(e) {
    numberOfClicks++;
    console.log(numberOfClicks);

    const pos = {
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY
    };

    // Check each circle for intersection with the click point
    // If intersected, clear it
    const newCircles = [];
    circles.forEach(circle => {
        if (doesIntersectCircle(pos, circle)) {
            // Although, this clears the entire canvas
            // You probably need to just clear the area of the given circle
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        } else {
            // Keep the circle
            newCircles.push(circle);
        }
    });
  circles.splice(0, circles.length);
  circles.push(...newCircles);
}

run();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="580" height="580"></canvas>
```

Comment: Uh, why would I do that?

Comment: Lots of folks can still see the original post in the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors here. First, when you try to clear the canvas `context.clearRect(canvas.width, canvas.height);` you should hav it as `ctx.clearRect(canvas.width, canvas.height);` so ctx instead of context. Second, the x, y, and radius variables are not global, so you should define them outside of the `drawCirlce` function. Third, the clearRect function takes 4 arguments, `x y width height`. Instead do `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`.

Comment: Parentheses here make no difference, both of those are evaluated into the same thing

Comment: yes i realized that